# How to pass the data to Specific fragment in Android Using ViewModel

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Question :

case 1 : I want to send data from Fragment A to FragmentB and dont want to observe value in FragmentC.

case 2 : I want to send data from Fragment A to FragmentC and dont want to observe value in FragmentB.

Actual Output :

case 1 : after sending data from FragmentA to FragmentB through
ViewModel but FragmentC also observed.

Expected Output :

case 1 : I want to pass data from FragmentA to FragmentB and i dont to
observe in FragmentC.

```
In MainActivity.java

        BlankFragment1  frg=new BlankFragment1();
        BlankFragment2 frg1=new BlankFragment2();
        BlankFragment3 frg2=new BlankFragment3();
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.f1, frg, "Frag_Top_tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.f2, frg1, "Frag_Middle_tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.f3, frg2, "Frag_Bottom_tag");
        transaction.commit();
```

```
MyViewModel.java

public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final SavedStateHandle state;
    private final MutableLiveData<String> messageContainerA;

    public MyViewModel(SavedStateHandle state) {
        this.state = state;

        messageContainerA = state.getLiveData("Default Message A");
    }

    
    public void sendMessageToA(String msg)
    {
        messageContainerA.setValue(msg);

    }
    public LiveData<String> getMessageContainerA() {
        return messageContainerA;
    }

    
}
```

```
In FragmentA



MyViewModel pagerAgentViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        binding.button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pagerAgentViewModel.sendMessageToA(binding.editTextTextPersonName.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

```
In FragmentB


 MyViewModel pagerAgentViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity().).get(MyViewModel.class);
        pagerAgentViewModel.getMessageContainerA().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), binding.button3::setText);
```

```
In FragmentC



MyViewModel pagerAgentViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        pagerAgentViewModel.getMessageContainerA().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), binding.tvb3::setText);
```

anyone please help me through this.

Thanks in Andvance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can't pass data to your view model in order to be observed in a specific fragment while some other fragments are observing to that live data too. I suggest to define separate live data objects to observe them from different fragments.